# Remove Blinking of button if selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a button if I select it then the button name should change and other checkboxes should be checked. But when I am clicking on button button name is changing but it is not clearly visible.

```
if([btn.identifier isEqualToString:@"CheckBox"] && [self.selectAllButton.titleLabel.text  isEqualToString:@"Select All"])
{

    [self.selectAllButton setTitle:@"Unselect All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.selectAllButton setSelected:YES];

    [self.selectAllButton setClipsToBounds:YES];
                    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

    [self.selectAllButton setTintColor:color];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setSelected:YES];
}
else if ([btn.identifier isEqualToString:@"CheckBox"] && [self.selectAllButton.titleLabel.text  isEqualToString:@"Unselect All"])

{

    [self.selectAllButton setTitle:@"Select All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.selectAllButton setSelected:NO];

    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setSelected:NO];
}
```

Can you please tell me why after clicking select all button the button is not showing.

Comment: UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]; what is this

Comment: i guess if you wan to hide your button then you should `setAlpha` instead `setTintColor`.

Comment: I don't want to hide my button. Button was highlighted by tintcolor that's why I made alpha of tintcolor as 0.0. If I will change alpha value to 1.0 or something then the button will be again highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You have set button color ! Why use the 0.0 for all colors ?

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
```

alpha:0.0 Means it is not visible change it as  alpha:1.0

Remove  `[self.selectAllButton setSelected:YES]; & [btn setSelected:YES];`

Comment: Actually before using this alpha:0.0 this button was highlighted with tint color that's why i made it like that.

Comment: Once check it any object (button , view , lable .. etc) change the alpha 0.0 to 1.0 then you under stand

Comment: No till now not resolved. Actually If I will change the alpha value to 1.0 then this button will be highlighted on click of button which I don't want. That's why I made it as 0.0

Comment: remove setSelected: YES statements

Comment: If I will make setSelected=No then it is affecting other functionalities. Whatever function I want to perform by clicking that button, it is not performing correctly.

Comment: Try this setHighlighted = NO

Comment: Actually I have already tried setHighlighted=NO. It's not working.